# What's the easiest way to combine specific columns of two matrices?

Tags: matrix, concatenation

given matrices

```
A = {{3, 10, 10, 5.`}, {4, 10, 10, 6.`}, {5, 10, 10, 7.`}}
B = {{6, 10, 10, 5.`}, {7, 10, 10, 6.`}, {8, 10, 10, 7.`}}
```

how can i get a matrix which has the combines the first column of A with the first coulumn of B and the last column of A?
Resulting in

```
C = {{3,6, 5.`}, {4,7, 6.`}, {5,8, 7.`}}
```

Thanky you in advance for any assistance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just try

```
 Transpose@{First/@A,First/@B,Last/@A}
```

or

```
 Transpose@{A[[All,1]],B[[All,1]],A[[All,4]]}
```

> {{3, 6, 5.}, {4, 7, 6.}, {5, 8, 7.}}

Comment: Than you very much